# How do I show only unmatched results via parsing a text file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method that searches lines in a text file and stores them in a hash based on a word list.

The method does two simple things:

If there is a match, it stores the line using a regular expression in the 'found' category, otherwise it stores the result in the 'unfound' category.

My question deals with the 'unfound' portion: EVERY line is going into unclassified. What I need is for unclassified transactions to ONLY be lines that AREN'T on the word list.

This is my wordlist:

```
words_to_check = ['BUILDING','LAKE','TREE']
```

This is my text path:

```
path_to_file = "/Users/name/Desktop/path_to_file"
```

File content example:

```
07/08/2013,"BUILDING",,100.00
07/08/2013,"LAKE",,50.00
07/08/2013,"TREE",,5.50
07/08/2013,"CAT",,10.50
07/08/2013,"DOG",,-19.87
```

This is the method that builds the hash:

```
def build_hash(path_to_file, words_to_check)
  trans_info = {
    :found => {},
    :unfound => {}
  }

  found = trans_info[:found]
  unfound = trans_info[:unfound]

  words_to_check.each do |word|
    found[word] = []
    unfound[:unfound] = []

      File.foreach(path_to_file) do |line|              
        if line.include?(word)
      date = /(?<Month>\d{1,2})\D(?<Day>\d{2})\D(?<Year>\d{4})/.match(line).to_s
      transaction = /(?<transaction>)#{word}/.match(line).to_s
      amount =/-+(?<dollars>\d+)\.(?<cents>\d+)/.match(line).to_s.to_f.round(2)

          # found word on list now push to array with hash keys
      found[word] << { 
        date: date, 
        transaction: transaction, 
        amount: amount 
      }

        else

      date = /(?<Month>\d{1,2})\D(?<Day>\d{2})\D(?<Year>\d{4})/.match(line).to_s
      transaction = /(?<Middle>)".*"/.match(line).to_s
      amount =/-*(?<dollars>\d+)\.(?<cents>\d+)/.match(line).to_s.to_f.round(2)     

      # push to unfound part of hash
          unfound[:unfound] << { 
        date: date, 
        transaction: transaction, 
        amount: amount
      } 

       end
      end
   end
    #found and unfound key/values will be returned
  return trans_info
 end
```

If you run this you will see that 'BUILDING', 'LAKE', 'TREE', 'CAT','DOG' are in `:unfound`.
Only 'CAT' and 'DOG' should be in `:unfound`.

This may seem like a simple `else` or conditional logic but I've researched and thought about other data structures but can't figure this out. Any advice or new ideas much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how you set up your loops.  Since you're checking each word independently, you're essentially requiring that ALL words in the list would have to be in a line to avoid going into the `:unfound` category.

Just as an example, look at the first line of the data file.

```
07/08/2013,"BUILDING",,100.00
```

On the first pass through the `words_to_check.each` loop, you compare that line to the first word in the list, which is `BUILDING`.  This is obviously a match, so the line is added to the `:found` category.  However, there are still two more words to compare.  On the second pass through the loop, you're comparing the same line to the word `LAKE`, so the match fails, and the line is added to the `:unfound` category.  Then the same thing happens for the word `TREE`.  Now the program finally moves on to checking the next line.

You're also having to read the file multiple times since the file loop is inside the word loop.  Since reading files is very slow, I'd reverse the order of those loops.  That is, I'd put the word loop on the inside.

You'll probably want to structure you loop more like this:

```
File.foreach(path_to_file) do |line|
  line_does_match = false # assume that we start without a match
  words_to_check.each do |word| # check the current line against all words
    if line.include? word
      line_does_match = true # record that we have a match
      break # stop the words_to_check.each loop
    end
  end
  # Now that we've determined whether the line matches ANY of the 
  # words in the list we can deal with it accordingly.
  if line_does_match
    # add it to the :found list
  else
    # add it to the :unfound list
  end
end
```

Comment: I appreciate you time. I think that will work but it won't group multiple keys or words together. I guess I can just sort the list later. Ultimately I wanted to group together all "TREE" results for example. Thanks for idea I'll try it out though.

Comment: You should be able to take the general idea and modify it to suit your needs.  The critical thing to remember is that since you have two loops involved you can't really treat each comparison as a free standing thing.  Every run of the inner loop that happens within each pass of the outer loop is related.  (I hope that makes sense...)

Comment: thank you so much for your patience. I have been trying so hard on this code (even though may be simple). I'll be studying your recommendations - thanks again!